# Python Mailchimp Transactional payload not being recognized by mailchimp template

Tags: python, django, mailchimp

I am using the `MailchimpTransactional` package to send an email with a dynamic body, and mailchimp is rendering the subject, from, to and other field correctly. However; the variables in the actual body of the template are not being populated in the mailchimp email. Below is my payload I am sending. Nothing in the `template_content` key is being used in the template:

Template code:

```
<header></header>
*|HTML:BODY|* 
<footer></footer>
```

Payload:

```
mailchimp = MailchimpTransactional.Client(MAILCHIMP_KEY)

message  = {
  'template_name': 'general-template',
  'merge_language': 'mailchimp',
  'template_content': [{
    'name': 'BODY',
    'content': '<h1>HEY LISTEN!</h1>'
  }],
  'message': {
    'to': [{
      'email': 'test1@example.com',
      'type': 'to'
    }, {
      'email': 'test@example.com',
      'type': 'cc'
    }],
    'subject': 'Test Subject',
    'attachments': [],
    'from_email': 'no-reply@test.com',
    'from_name': None,
    'headers': {
      'Reply-To': '{}'
    }
  }
}

mailchimp.messages.send_template(message)
```

The email sends just find, however, all the email returns is below:

[image: email image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `mc:edit` tags in your template as described at https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/templates-dynamic-content/#editable-content-areas?

Comment: @Marco I have been thinking that my tags may be wrong in my mailchimp template too, however; I can execute the same script and payload in ruby and it works as expected, so I thought I was doing something wrong in python.

Comment: The solution was move the marge language down inside of the Message dict and define my global_merge_vars in the message dict.

Comment: You can post an answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was move the marge language down inside of the Message dict and define my global_merge_vars in the message dict.